# should i ignore the .editorconfig file while laravel 8 project deployement

Tags: laravel, deployment, editorconfig

one is the .editorconfig file and other one is .ignore file, tell me , should i included it or not, other files are ignored as you can see below.

**.ignore file**

```
/public/hot
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
/vendor
.env
.env.backup
.phpunit.result.cache
docker-compose.override.yml
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
/.idea
/.phpIntel
/.vscode

.editorconfig
```

**.editorConfig file**

```
root = true

[*]
charset = utf-8
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[*.md]
trim_trailing_whitespace = false

[*.{yml,yaml}]
indent_size = 2
```

**Noob Coder**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.editorconfig` file is used to keep consistency in the coding environment when you work with multiple team members. It helps you to keep all the code in the same formating.

So as per my view, If you are working with multiple developers then you should not ignore it else you can ignore it.